# Google Assistant advanced responses with API.AI

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es, google-assistant-sdk

I already have a webhook, and I am using it to change the assistant answers.
But I can't figure out how to send a suggestions card or a link, as you can send them from **API.AI** web GUI (*From the add content button*).

Should I send them as a `JSON object` under the `data` name.

[image: https://api.ai/docs/fulfillment#response]
[API.AI webhook documentation](https://api.ai/docs/fulfillment#response)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The general form for the JSON body of a response to a API.AI fulfillment webhook call that will include a Action on Google rich response for a simple response and a card is below.  If you want to use lists or carousel the documentation is [here](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/helpers#list_and_carousel_option):

```
{
  "speech": "This is a API.AI default speech response",
  "displayText": "This is a API.AI default display text response",
  "data": {
    "google": {
      "expectUserResponse": true,
      "isSsml": false,
      "noInputPrompts": [],
      "richResponse": {
        "items": [
          {
            "simpleResponse": {
              "textToSpeech": "This is a simple speech response for Actions on Google.",
              "displayText": "This is a simple display text response for Action on Google."
            }
          },
          {
            "basicCard": {
              "title": "Title: this is a title",
              "subtitle": "This is a subtitle",
              "formattedText": "This is a basic card.  Text in a basic card can include \"quotes\" and most other unicode characters including emoji .  Basic cards also support some markdown formatting like *emphasis* or _italics_, **strong** or __bold__, and ***bold itallic*** or ___strong emphasis___ as well as other things like line  \nbreaks",
              "image": {
                "url": "https://developers.google.com/actions/images/badges/XPM_BADGING_GoogleAssistant_VER.png",
                "accessibilityText": "Image alternate text"
              },
              "buttons": [
                {
                  "title": "This is a button",
                  "openUrlAction": {
                    "url": "https://assistant.google.com/"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```