# Emoji in SimpleResponse

Tags: actions-on-google, api-ai

https://stackoverflow.com/a/45890852/8413869

from the above answer, I got to know that emojis can be passed in Button formatted text.

But I am looking for emojis like google have it in Bubble response.
[image]

I tried to pass unicode in simple response but no luck.

```
....."data": {
        "google": {
            "expectUserResponse": true,
            "richResponse": {
                "items": [
                    {
                        "simpleResponse": {
                            "ssml": "<speak>Hello. How are you ? </speak>",
                            "displayText": "Hello U+1F600., how are you ? "
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "suggestions": [],
                "linkOutSuggestion": {}
            }
        }
    }.....
```

Is there any way to do this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I made it work with this uni code " \uD83D\uDE00"
I just copied emoji from https://emojipedia.org/ which gave me this unicode

Answer (score 4):

You can include emoji in simple responses for Google Assistant apps by including the actual emoji in the string instead of the Unicode code point for the emoji.  Change your response to the below and it should work:

```
....."data": {
        "google": {
            "expectUserResponse": true,
            "richResponse": {
                "items": [
                    {
                        "simpleResponse": {
                            "ssml": "<speak>Hello. How are you ? </speak>",
                            "displayText": "Hello ., how are you ? "
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "suggestions": [],
                "linkOutSuggestion": {}
            }
        }
    }.....
```

Comment: thanks for replying, but I am using java webhook and preparing string. I don't think I can copy and paste this emoji in string.

Comment: Here is a StackOverlflow question on how to include emoji in Java strings: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26231263/create-string-with-emoji-unicode-flag-countries

Comment: thanks, 
I made it work with this uni code " \uD83D\uDE00"
I just copied emoji from https://emojipedia.org/ which gave me this unicode